# Silverlight 5.0 ColorAnimation of SolidColorBrush fails with "Cannot resolve TargetName"

Tags: silverlight

We have 3 animations in a storyboard that works fine in Silverlight 4, but fails in Silverlight 5 with the above-mentioned error. The animation is pretty simple:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="categoryChangeStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="clueTransform"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                Duration="0:0:0.4"
                To="1.05"
                RepeatBehavior="3x"
                AutoReverse="True"
                />
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="clueTransform"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                Duration="0:0:0.4"
                To="1.1"
                RepeatBehavior="3x"
                AutoReverse="True"
                />
            <ColorAnimation
                Duration="0:0:0.4"
                Storyboard.TargetName="categoryForegroundBrush"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                From="Black"
                To="LightGreen"
                RepeatBehavior="3x"
                AutoReverse="True"
                />
        </Storyboard>
```

and the object it's animating is pretty simple as well:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="clue" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" Text="clue" FontSize="35" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MaxWidth="300" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,90,80,0" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
               <TextBlock.Foreground>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" x:Name="categoryForegroundBrush" />
                </TextBlock.Foreground>
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="clueTransform"/>
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            </TextBlock>
```

When we call

```
categoryChangeStoryboard.Begin();
```

We get the following error -- only for Silverlight 5:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve TargetName categoryForegroundBrush.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(DependencyObject obj, String name)
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.Begin()
   at BCL.FLY.FLYVisual.CoreStateUpdateEvent(Object sender, FLYStateUpdateEventArgs e)
   at BCL.FLY.FLYCore.OnStateUpdateEvent(FLYStateUpdateEventArgs e)
   at BCL.FLY.FLYCore.Report(String msg, GameEventType t, Butterfly b)
   at BCL.FLY.FLYCore.DebugGotoLevel(Int32 i)
   at BCL.FLY.FLYVisual.DebugGotoLevel(Int32 n)
   at BCL.FLY.FLYGame.GotoLevel(Int32 i)
   at C8Live.MainPage.lvlSkip_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(List`1 unselectedItems, List`1 selectedItems)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.NotifyListItemSelected(ListBoxItem listBoxItem, Boolean isSelected)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnIsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet, Boolean isBindingInStyleSetter)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty property, Boolean b)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnListBoxItemClicked(ListBoxItem item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts? Removing that single ColorAnimation does fix the problem, but we'd prefer to keep it in.

Comment: Does labelStyle set the Foreground brush?

Comment: This is very wierd. I've copied the code to a simple project and everything works alright. If you can, can you share the style aswell. It seems to me that your style overrides your Foreground color of your Textblock and it is thus unable to find the overwritten SolidColorBrush x:Named categoryForeGroundBrush

Comment: @Danimal, I ran your code in a sample project and it worked fine. I'd need to see your labelStyle to repro this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reproduced the issue as follows.

Because you set your Foreground in xaml and add a x:Name to the brush it cannot change in code behind. The order of which styles get applied is the Style resource first and then anything inside the control it self, override the style.

Now like I said changing the color in the code behind reproduces the issue because it doesn't contain a name property. As you might see in the next picture, I've found the solution already and that is by setting the value of the DependecyProperty `NameProperty`.
 [image: Exception]

Add the code,

```
solidColorBrush.SetValue(NameProperty, "categoryForegroundBrush");
```

And you should not have the issue again.